# "What went wrong?" Vs. "What did go wrong?"

Tags: idiomatic-language, emphatic-polarity

I came across the phrase "**What went wrong?**" and I doubt if it has a correct form "**What did go wrong**?" or it would be already not idiomatic in this way. Is it idiomatic to use "What did go wrong?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second form is idiomatic with one caveat.

When we say it, we emphasize *did*. This means that we would also emphasize it in writing:

> What *did* go wrong?

It doesn't sound right if we don't emphasize *did*. Without the emphasis, we would revert back to the simpler *What went wrong?*

When we do emphasize it, we are generally comparing it to something that *didn't* go wrong:

> "It all went wrong."
>   "You mean the food didn't get there?"
>   "No, actually that part was fine."
>   "Okay, so *what **did** go wrong*?"

Answer (score -2):

These two phrases give the same meaning, but we usually use 'what **went** wrong'.